# jOOQ - Building a dynamic `CASE WHEN` with DSL

Tags: java, dynamic-sql, jooq

I'm working with jOOQ and want to construct a dynamic `CASE WHEN` expression using the DSL. The desired outcome is a structure like this:

```java
var myCase = DSL.case_()
  .when(condition1, result1)
  .when(condition2, result2)
  // ... additional WHEN clauses
  .else_(defaultValue);
```

However, a naive approach using a loop and subsequent `.when` calls encounters an issue. Since the return type of `DSL.case_()` changes after the first `.when`, adding a dummy initial condition like `DSL.falseCondition()` becomes necessary. This code below works, but feels clunky:

```java
var myCase = DSL.case_()
  .when(DSL.falseCondition(), null); // Hack to change myCase's type

for (var entry:conditions)
  myCase.when( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() )

return myCase.else_(defaultValue)
```

Is there a way to avoid this hack and build a dynamic `CASE WHEN` expression in jOOQ using the DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```java
if (conditions.isEmpty())
    return defaultValue;

CaseConditionStep<T> c = null;

for (var entry : conditions)
    c = c == null 
        ? DSL.when(entry.getKey(), getValue()) 
        : c.when(entry.getKey(), getValue());

return c.else_(defaultValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll make a CaseBuilder class out of it.